# In puppet, can you supress a specific notice log entry? LVM forge module

Tags: puppet

With the LVM module from the Forge, the "size" property sets the desired size of the logical volume.  The "size_is_minsize" parameter says that "size" is just the minimum desired size (it's OK if the logical volume is larger than "size").  When this is the case, however, a Notice is generated on every puppet run.  For example:

`Notice: /Stage[main]/Filesystems/Logical_volume[tmp]/size: size changed '106G' to '100G'`

Is there any way to avoid this notice?  For example, can we change the "size" parameter to be 106G within the provider or manifest?

Comment: Can you link to the module in question?

Comment: https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/lvm is the module we're using.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the 100G in your code to 106G? Your manifest should reflect the actual state of the server, if you want to do this correctly. If you get this message, I'd recommend changing the puppet config/hiera values for this server to reflect the actual size.

Or am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: Well, the point is we don't know what size it might be, and the module allows us to specify a size, but if it exists and is larger, it would otherwise set an error. We're OK with it being larger in this case. . .